# Gulp Image Hash in Less Files

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm trying to find a gulp task that will look through all of my less files and update any image paths with a hashed query string for cache reasons.

I can find plenty that will do files and file refs but can't seem to find anything that will work through paths in existing css/less files.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you write one? It could be a great resource to share.

Comment: OK task may have been the wrong word. More a package I can write a task for. All packages I can find seem to be full of vulnerabilities or only does files. New to gulp so apolgies if I'm misunderstanding

Comment: My advice would be to attempt it yourself, and ask more questions if you get stuck. At the moment this question is off-topic as you're asking for a "offsite resource". See  [help/on-topic]